# Supervisor setup on AWS AMI Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, supervisord, amazon-linux

I'm trying to get supervisor working to make sure my queue system is always running.

Here are the steps I took, which I pieced together from various sources: (Ran as root or super user)

1. Ran:

   ```
   # easy_install supervisor
   # echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf
   # vi supervisord.conf
   ```
2. Pasted the following to end of file:

   ```
   command=/usr/bin/php /path/to/AppName/artisan --env=production --timeout=240 queue:listen
   ```
3. Ran:

   ```
   # supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
   # supervisorctl
   supervisor> status
   supervisor>
   ```

   It does not display anything.
4. Ran:

   ```
   # service supervisord reload
   supervisord: unrecognized service
   ```

Comment: Which version of CentOS? Why did you use easy_install?

Comment: It is Amazon's AMI Linux http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/ I am trying to find which Centos they used to build it.

Comment: Found this from 2010, "...The Amazon Linux AMI is based on RHEL 5.x and parts of RHEL6. One of our goals is binary compatibility with RHEL 5.x, and therefore CentOS5.x. Astute users will note that our kernel is based on 2.6.34, and we have engineered the image to conform to a cloud environment. For example, the lack of Xorg support helps to keep the images small and lean. The goal of the Amazon Linux AMI is to provide an image for use in the cloud and to serve as reference image of EC2 best practices..."

Comment: I used Easy Install, because that seemed like the easiest way.

Comment: They _forked_ from CentOS, and did not maintain compatibility. If you are using Amazon Linux, you should not mention CentOS or assume that it will act in any way similarly to CentOS. And if that was meant to be a showcase of best practices, they failed miserably. Amazon Linux is one of the least stable and most unreliable Linux distributions I have ever seen. Not to mention thoroughly undocumented.

Comment: My apologies, thanks for the info I'll edit my question and keep my fingers crossed for a working solution. Which free distro do you recommend for the task at hand? (Supervisord with Redis and Laravel)

Comment: I wouldn't bother with supervisord at all. In recent distributions (such as the real CentOS 7) systemd is perfectly capable of handling that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to get supervisord running as a service you need an `/etc/init.d/supervisord` file.
i used https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Supervisor/initscripts/master/redhat-init-equeffelec
with mods to match the path which easy_install put the binaries at (`/usr/local/bin/`) and to find the pid and logs in `/var/run/` and `/var/log/`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For now I was able to get supervisord working locally on my Ubuntu workstation with no problems. Since it is so much more hassle free on Ubuntu and I won't need to scale out my Queue server, I am going to setup a new instance for my development/queue system on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok I had to return to this for another App we have running on AMI. I was able to modify the start up script to match the paths like you mentioned and added to chkconfig. Its working now even on forced reboot.

Answer (score 4):

I just spent a couple hours on this, trying to get supervisor and Amazon Linux AMI to play nice. I was experiencing exactly the symptoms you mentioned.

Some quirks:

- go ahead and include `-c /etc/supervisord.conf` (or whatever your path) on any `supervisord` or `supervisorctl` command, and make sure you run from the same user every time.
- in your `/etc/supervisord.conf`, when you append the command, make sure you prefix the name with 'program:', like so:

  ```
  [program:queue]
  command=/usr/bin/php /path/to/AppName/artisan --env=production --timeout=240 queue:listen
  ```

Once I did the above, supervisorctl FINALLY recognized the queue process/program.

I still haven't gotten `sudo service supervisor restart` to recognize supervisor as a service - I suspect it's because I don't have an upstart script that I've seen mentioned in a handful of places. Not sure I need one at this point.

Some debugging techniques I used:

- `ps aux | grep super` to see if it's running
- sudo vim to edit the `/etc/supervisord.conf` and `sudo /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisord.conf` then `avail`, `reload`, `update` etc. to update (rather than editing .ebextensions and pushing to elastic beanstalk everytime)