# supervisorctl: command not found

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, supervisord

as ec2-user:

```
[ec2-user@stg etc]$ sudo supervisorctl status
sudo: supervisorctl: command not found
```

as root:

```
[ec2-user@stg etc]$ sudo su -
Last login: Tue Jun  6 03:02:55 UTC 2017 on pts/1
[root@stg ~]# supervisorctl status
kafka                            BACKOFF   Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
zookeeper                        RUNNING   pid 24697, uptime 0:25:11
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening. 
I checked sudoers file but did not find something meaningful. Please help.

Comment: What version of the os are running on the ec2 instance? This looks like Amazon linux. Also this might be helpful https://serverfault.com/questions/672891/supervisor-setup-on-aws-ami-linux#697162

Answer (score 5):

This usually means that the command is not on the EC2 user's PATH.

If you do `echo $PATH` in both bash sessions you still see that root has `/usr/sbin/` on their path.

To fix this, you can add to the ec2-user's path by adding the following to .bashrc:

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin/"`

Alternatively, the full path to the executable, `sudo /usr/sbin/supervisorctl` should work.

Comment: **root path**
`[root@stg ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin`

**ec2-user path**

`[ec2-user@stg ~]$ echo $PATH
/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
`

Answer (score 2):

after going back and forward, it was simple 
supervisor uses python 2.6 and doesnt work with 2.7 on amazon linux ami, apparently (rhel fedora) 
u can verify this by

```
#python2.6 -c "import supervisor; print('success')"
```

success

```
#python2.7 -c "import supervisor; print('success')"
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named supervisor

so u need to tell the system to use 2.6 instead of 2.7 -  and u really have to make sure that this is safe to do  - u dont want others app to start messing up. (am assuming u have both 2.6 and .27 installed already)

so steps to fix:

first run this command

```
# sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

a menu will appear select the right one.
#

There are 2 programs which provide 'python'.

```
Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/bin/python2.7
   2           /usr/bin/python2.6

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2
#
```

choose the right one and ur set to go.

finally, try this one :

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/supervisord start
Starting supervisord:                                      [  OK  ]
```

problem Solved!